# C++ QuickSort Isn't Working Correctly

Tags: c++, algorithm, quicksort

I am attempting to modify some QuickSort code to have a random number as the pivot.

However, while testing program it doesn't sort correctly. I'm unsure why this is doing this.

```
int random (int num) {
    int random = rand() % (num - 1);
    return random;
}

int* partition (int* first, int* last);
void quickSort(int* first, int* last) {
    if (last - first <= 1) return;

    int* pivot = partition(first, last);
    quickSort(first, pivot);
    quickSort(pivot + 1, last);
}

int* partition (int* first, int* last) {
    //--int pivot = *(last - 1);    
    int* pos = (first + random(last - first));
    int pivot = *pos;
    int* i = first;
    int* j = last - 1;

    for (;;) {
        while (*i < pivot && i < last) i++;
        while (*j >= pivot && j > first) j--;
        if (i >= j) break;
        swap (*i, *j);
    }
    swap (*pos, *i);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Quicksort is great because you can actually test the parts separately -- you can try testing the partition function to see if it works, then test the recursive quicksort separately.  (Also note that your definition of `random` might crash if `num = 1`.)

Comment: What do you mean increase it? I can't increase it if it goes out of bounds.

Comment: That last `swap (*pos, *i)` looks suspicious. I assume it's supposed to move the pivot value to its final destination but after the partition loop the value at `*pos` probably isn't the pivot any longer.

Comment: You can accept an answer for each question you have asked. It appears marked as accepted for future readers, showing that the question has already has an accepted answer. You have asked a few questions and accepted none, which may put people off answering your questions. If you have not accepted answers because you don't consider any of them suitable, then you could indicate that in comments to answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [first implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714207/c-quicksort-pivot-optimization) worked but had degenerate behavior with specific datasets. The pivot in your original working code was `*(last - 1)` so the simplest fix would be to swap a random element with `*(last - 1)`. The rest of your original partition code would work unchanged.

Comment: Do all references to last - 1 need to be changed to the random number variable/

Comment: @Andrew: No, just add some code to swap a random element with the element at `(last - 1)`. Do that before the line that says `int pivot = *(last - 1)` and no other changes to your original code are needed.